# how to use a animated image in appcelerator

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am using appcelerator to develop a app on iOS. However - I am not very clear on how to show an animated gif.

sdk-version: 5.0.2.GA

I am using the following code..

```
 imageFOO = Ti.UI.createImageView ({ 
        image : '/loafing.gif', 
        width : '100%', height : '90%' 
        });
```

or

```
imageBAR = Ti.UI.createImageView ({ 
        image : '/search.gif', 
        height : '24', 
        width : '24' 
        });
```

But the animation is not working. How would I make the animation work in animated gifs ?

Sriram

Answer (score 1):

Appcelerator Titanium can't handle GIF files from itself. You have to use a module like this: https://github.com/mpociot/TiImageFromGIF